# What is the content of the elevation map geotiff produced by Autodesk Forge's Reality Capture API?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-realitycapture

I am looking for information which describes the elevation map geotiff produced by Autodesk Forge's Reality Capture (Recap) API. Is this a colorized "heatmap" or is this a matrix of elevation values in meters, feet, etc?

I read through the documentation provided by Autodesk, but it did not specify, nor provide an example. I also searched online, including Stackoverflow, and found no mention of it in other questions.

Ref: https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/reality-capture/v1/reference/http/photoscene-POST/

Answer (score 1):

[GeoTIFF](http://trac.osgeo.org/geotiff/) is a standard format that can be read by many (GIS) applications.

It actually encodes the elevation values, and the colorized heat map is just one way of rendering/representing it.

For example one can load it with the `tifffile` module in Python and it renders like below with the colors of the map customizable:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is this a general comment about geotiffs, or a comment on the output of Autodesk Forge's Recap API?

Comment: I down-voted this answer because it is a general statement about geotiffs, whereas the question is specifically about Autodesk Forge's Recap API.